LiveActivity UI not showing in flutter ios app
I'm implementing iOS Live Activities in my Flutter app using the live_activities package. While the activity seems to be created (I can get the activity token, and clicking the Dynamic Island opens the app), the LiveActivity UI does not show up as expected.
Logs:
The following errors/warnings appear in the logs:
Not updating lastKnownShmemState in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6000006bc7e0> (Domain: group.powerdock.sessionactivity, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): 34 -> 33

What Works:
The activity token is created successfully.
Clicking the Dynamic Island opens my app.
What Does Not Work:
The LiveActivity UI does not display on the lock screen or elsewhere.
